# Did Turkey invade Cyprus to keep the USSR out? Is there really CIA files that prove this for real?

Tags: cold-war, turkey, coup, cyprus

[I have watched an video about the invasion but one of the comments made me think a little bit different.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPxyCuzFGOQ)

> The real reason behind the Cypriot War of 1974 was to prevent the
>   (Greek) Cypriot government of Makarios from allowing the USSR to build
>   a military base on the island, a base that would be close to the sea
>   or on a coastal position, and thus allow for Communist Russia to exert
>   naval influence in the eastern Mediterranean. Sadly, it was all agreed
>   upon in advance by members of NATO (USA, UK, Turkey and Greece at
>   least), even down to the small details of exactly which areas and even
>   streets the Turkish army would capture. Anglo-American divide-and-rule
>   tactics at their most strikingly effective. If you want to know more,
>   check out the CIA files that were declassified back in 2004.

I couldn't find these files the commentor claimed but lets go on.

Also the translation of the Greek comment replies translated to English by a good person for me.

> He says that the Greek junta was put in power by the Americans. Also
>   Cyprus had joined the non-aligned movement and was having talks with
>   the USSR. The partition of the island was even agreed upon in 1956
>   between the democratically elected Greek government and the American
>   representative Kohler , while the Cypriot war of independence against
>   the Brits was still raging on.

There is more that brought my attention. Makarious The Third is known for its Communist thoughts.

What I want to know is... Is there any proof?

What I'd like to know is if there are CIA files that proves this. I am not some denier or anything.

Comment: Voting to close for promoting opinion.

Comment: Okay, I still think it is not a very good question for this site, but some clarification about those CIA documents would be interesting.

Comment: @TomasBy thats why I am here...

Answer (score 3):

3% of the island of Cyprus still belongs to the United Kingdom (it is not a lease, as it was never transferred to Cyprus upon independence), within which the largest British military installation outside the mainland U.K. exists. A rival nation's installation on Cyprus could not be more than 50km away from the U.K.'s.

I cannot imagine the Soviet Union taking the risk when it could more easily use its client, Syria, as Russia does now.

There is no reason to believe this is more likely than the historically accepted reason: to prevent the Cypriot coup d'etat from self-annexing the island to Greece.

Answer (score -1):

> The real reason behind the Cypriot War of 1974 was to prevent the (Greek) Cypriot government of Makarios from allowing the USSR to build a military base on the island,

That's highly debatable, looking with 20/20 hindsight. America (in particular) and the UK weren't exactly keen on that possibility, so much is true.

Turkey wasn't going to turn such a golden opportunity away to occupy the island - make that: prevent communism taking over the island. So, if the USA/UK approved of a take over to prevent communism, they were most happy to oblige. They didn't really invade to keep the USSR out, but to get Turkey in.

Quite a few politicians who didn't do exactly as required by the USA or the UK were tarred being communists.